# Encrypting SD card

Tags: 14.04, encryption

I have a small capacity SSD drive on my laptop, to compensate I got a 32GB SD card in my laptop which goes in `/media/usr/...` and I want to store files and stuff on it. The problem would be if someone take out the SD card from laptop they can access the content. So how can I encrypt the SD card in a way that it only works on my laptop and nothing else?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You create an **LUKS** container on a partition or your whole SD card.

I give you the GUI version:

Open up `Disks`, choose your SD card, click on the wheel and choose Format. For *Type*, choose `Crypted compatible with linux`, enter a passphrase and choose Format.

You will be asked for this passphrase when you mount your SD card. Don't forget it.

Caution: You will loose all the data on the SD card.

[image: Disks LUKS format]

Comment: Interesting. But the option is not available for me. Which packages do I need to install to make this work? I have a fresh default Ubuntu + KDE Plasma manually installed. Version of Disks is "gnome-disk-utility 40.1 - UDisks 2.9.2 (built against 2.9.2)"

Comment: I also do not see this option on Ubuntu 20.0.4

Answer (score 1):

The accepted answer did not worked for me:

1. [image]
2. [image]
3. [image]
4. [image]
5. [image]
6. [image]

Source: https://www.howtoforge.com/tutorial/encrypt-usb-drive-on-ubuntu/